# How can save my data into the bmp format in Octave?

Tags: octave, bmp, save-as

Dear Sir: I am new with Octave and I have a test object and need to save it's data into the bmp format.

```
Rx=100;   
Ry=100;       
k=-1;           
x=y=(-100:1:100);
[x, y] = meshgrid (x, y);
z=(((x.^2)/Rx)+((y.^2)/Ry))./((1+sqrt(1-((1+k)*x.^2/Rx.^2)-((1+k)*y.^2/Ry.^2))));
mesh(x,y,z);
```

My question is how can I save this (x,y,z) data into the bmp format with gray=256?
Could any one please help me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: http://www.dm.unibo.it/~achilles/calc/octave.html/Loading-and-Saving-Images.html
can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the code kss211, but your question is not completely clear to me. What do you mean by "save this xyz"? If you want to save the resulting figure it's one thing, and if you want to save the xyz values it's another. If you want to just save the figure, in principle it should be as simple as `saveas( gcf, 'out.bmp' )`, or `print(gcf, 'out.bmp', '-dbmp' )`, but there's a chance the `.bmp` format won't be supported, in which case your best bet would be to save as something else first (e.g. replace bmp to png above), and then convert png to bmp from your OS utilities

Comment: Dear Sir. Thank you very much for your comment. With my test code at the end I can save my x,y,z data with stl format by "surf2stl (x,y,z,'test.stl');". But at this time I would like to save it into .bmp but not .stl. Or could you please show me how is the code that you say I can save my data in to the .png. Then I will try to convert this png to bmp and see if it is working well with my project or not? Thank's again.